# Using git to manage 2 different repositories in same folder

Tags: git

I have a git repository which I clone from github. This repository contains a lot code . I am now editing some of the files there. But these edits are something so specific that I have another git repository to maintain these changes. I doubt it would ever get merged with the original github repository. But a lot of the code I write depends on the original git repository and some include direct changes to the files cloned from the repository .When I try to update the repository to the newest version(which is essential to remove bugs) even my changes would disappear. So what is the best way to maintain this project? I can remove the files I have modified from version control pull the latest version in and add them back. But this is not the right way to do it. Whats the best way to overcome this?

Comment: you want to read about [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Comment: Why will a local branch not be sufficient for the time being?  It would make rebasing from the origin repo updates much easier than your current workflow sounds.

Comment: Because I have to share the code with others working on the same project. So I have to push it onto a central repository. Also how does a local branch solve the issue when I have to update to a newer version of the original cloned repository

Comment: Git supports using more than one remote repository (it's a lot easier for humans to deal with just one though). The only thing "magical" or "central" about origin is that we use it as default by convention. Nothing stops you from pushing the branch to a different remote to share it with your colleagues without pushing it back to the origin.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. But what about the conflicts between my project and the original one when I update. Wont I have to make all the changes from scratch on the branch I update?